# URL Generation for Routes in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm considering using Express framework in my next node.js project. However, a stumbling block for me is non-existence of URL generation for routes like in most other non-Sinatra based frameworks, examples- Django, Flask, Rails etc.

I tried looking for some Connect middleware to serve my task and I did find Barista, Escort, Sherpa and the likes but looking at their GitHub pages, all seem dead and in-active. So, I don't want to go for something that's not maintained anymore for obvious reasons.

My main concern here is that the project may get really large and it WILL be a pain to update URLs in every page whenever business and/or aesthetic requirements change.

Is there something that I failed to see in the docs/tests? If not, then how do I extend the routing framework in Express to do URL generation and make this wrapper available in my views as well as controller functions?

**UPDATE: (22/3/2012)** I found this page: https://github.com/clyfe/tweet_express/wiki/TODO which specified some routers that do URL generation and stumbled upon the escort router which can also interface with express.

Comment: sure express can do a lot of stuff but there are a lot of frameworks built on top of express or even just on node.js itself. My personal favorite is Hapi.js. theres also sails. or just pure node if your crazy enough. i've used both of these in production environments. in the case of hapi what you are really probably looking for is url params. but your not limited there are tons of frameworks to pick from in node.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might try [Locomotive](http://locomotivejs.org/), which is built on Express.

It does much more than route generation. From the docs: "Locomotive brings additional MVC-based structure, for architecting larger applications, while leveraging the power of Express and Connect middleware."

[Locomotive's router generates helpers](http://locomotivejs.org/guide/routing.html) that are automatically available to controllers and views.

Comment: Note in 2019: Locomotive hasn't been updated since 2014.

Answer (score 15):

Or stick with express and use the package [reversable-router](https://github.com/web-napopa/node-reversable-router).

Example from the readme:

```
app.get('/admin/user/:id', 'admin.user.edit', function(req, res, next){
    //...
});

//.. and a helper in the view files:
url('admin.user.edit', {id: 2})
```

Comment: Note in 2019: named-routes hasn't been maintained since 2016.

Answer (score 0):

[From @freakish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12854940/122441):

There is no out of the box mechanism for that. However you can mimic Django's style like that: define `urls.js` file which will hold an array of URLs. First start with:

**myviews.js**

```
exports.Index = function( req, res, next ) {
    res.send( "hello world!" );
};
```

**urls.js**

```
var MyViews = require( "mywviews.js" );

module.exports = [
    { name : "index", pattern : "/", view : MyViews.Index }
]
```

Now in **app.js** ( or whatever the main file is ) you need to bind urls to Express. For example like this:

**app.js**

```
var urls = require( "urls.js" );

for ( var i = 0, l = urls.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    var url = urls[ i ];
    app.all( url.pattern, url.view );
};
```

Now you can define custom helper ( Express 3.0 style ):

```
var urls = require( "urls.js" ), l = urls.length;
app.locals.url = function( name ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
        var url = urls[ i ];
        if ( url.name === name ) {
            return url.pattern;
        }
    };
};
```

and you can easily use it in your template. Now the problem is that it does not give you fancy URL creation mechanism like in Django ( where you can pass additional parameters to `url` ). On the other hand you can modify `url` function and extend it. I don't want to go into all details here, but here's an example how to use regular expressions ( you should be able to combine these to ideas together ):

[Express JS reverse URL route (Django style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027574/express-js-reverse-url-route-django-style)

Note that I posted the question, so I had the same problem some time ago. :D