# Express JS reverse URL route (Django style)

Tags: node.js, routes, express

I'm using Express JS and I want a functionality similar to Django's `reverse` function. So if I have a route, for example

```
app.get('/users/:id/:name', function(req, res) { /* some code */ } )
```

I'd like to use a function for example

```
reverse('/users/:id/:name', 15, 'John');
```

or even better

```
reverse('/users/:id/:name', { id : 15, name : 'John' });
```

which will give me the url `/users/15/John`. Does such function exist? And if not then do you have any ideas how to write such function (considering Express' routing algorithm)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is your code:

```
function reverse(url, obj) { 
    return url.replace(/(\/:\w+\??)/g, function (m, c) { 
        c=c.replace(/[/:?]/g, ''); 
        return obj[c] ? '/' + obj[c] : ""; 
    }); 
}

reverse('/users/:id/:name', { id: 15, name: 'John' });
reverse('/users/:id?', { id: 15});
reverse('/users/:id?', {});
```

Comment: I thought about something like this (and actually I did implement this simple case), but unfortunetly Express uses `?` as a special character. This makes things a bit more complicated, because for url `/users/:id?` both `/users` and `/users/1` match it.

Comment: Updated. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah, I think that will do the job. Thanks!

Comment: This is not reverse routing, reason one wants to do reverse routing is because the URL structure might be redefined by the user. E.g. in Django reverse routing is done by giving the *name of the view* and parameters which in turn gives a URL. Reversing means here exactly that, if one restructures urls the links keeps working. Your example uses the URL directly and is nothing more than a URL builder.

Comment: @Ciantic This is the core of reverse routing. Creating `name:url` mapping is trivial.

Answer (score 7):

I've just created the package [reversable-router](https://github.com/web-napopa/node-reversable-router) that solves this along other problems for the routing.

Example from the readme:

```
app.get('/admin/user/:id', 'admin.user.edit', function(req, res, next){
    //...
});

//.. and a helper in the view files:
url('admin.user.edit', {id: 2})
```