# is it possible to name routes in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

Basic route is like this:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});
```

Is it possible to name that route and have it available in any template so it can be used like this:

```
app.get('/', name="index", function(req, res){
  res.send('hello world');
});

Go to site <a href="{% url index %}">index page</a>.
```

Inspiration comes from Django :)

Comment: A couple of things you may want to look at: [express-resource](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource) for consistent naming, and check out how locomotive implements [urlFor](http://locomotivejs.org/guide/datastores.html).

Comment: If you ever come back to this issue, take a look at [Shrinkroute](http://npmjs.org/package/shrinkroute). It's actively maintained and works with Express 3.

Comment: +1 from me for mentioning Django [`{% url %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no out of the box mechanism for that. However you can mimic Django's style like that: define `urls.js` file which will hold an array of URLs. First start with:

**myviews.js**

```
exports.Index = function( req, res, next ) {
    res.send( "hello world!" );
};
```

**urls.js**

```
var MyViews = require( "mywviews.js" );

module.exports = [
    { name : "index", pattern : "/", view : MyViews.Index }
]
```

Now in **app.js** ( or whatever the main file is ) you need to bind urls to Express. For example like this:

**app.js**

```
var urls = require( "urls.js" );

for ( var i = 0, l = urls.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    var url = urls[ i ];
    app.all( url.pattern, url.view );
};
```

Now you can define custom helper ( Express 3.0 style ):

```
var urls = require( "urls.js" ), l = urls.length;
app.locals.url = function( name ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
        var url = urls[ i ];
        if ( url.name === name ) {
            return url.pattern;
        }
    };
};
```

and you can easily use it in your template. Now the problem is that it does not give you fancy URL creation mechanism like in Django ( where you can pass additional parameters to `url` ). On the other hand you can modify `url` function and extend it. I don't want to go into all details here, but here's an example how to use regular expressions ( you should be able to combine these to ideas together ):

[Express JS reverse URL route (Django style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10027574/express-js-reverse-url-route-django-style)

Note that I posted the question, so I had the same problem some time ago. :D

Comment: The point is that with this you can change your urls without changing strings in all your templates. It's bad to hard code urls ;)

Comment: freakish: thanks, when i start writing my app i will make this in to a component :) for easier use.

I'm not sure how i will structure my app, but it is possible to make something django's app structure.

Answer (score 4):

I found express-reverse to nicely solve this issue

https://github.com/dizlexik/express-reverse

It augments the standard routing allowing you to pass the route's name as first argument

```
app.get('test', '/hello/:x', function(req, res, next) {
    res.end('hello ' + req.params.x);
});
```

Let you build the url from inside a template by name

```
<a href="<%= url('test', { x: 'world' }) %>">Test</a>
```

Let you redirect to an url by name

```
app.get('/test-redirect', function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirectToRoute('test', { x: 'world' });
});
```

Comment: The problem with this one is that it's not working `express.Router()`, so you cannot use `router.route('/url').get().post().put()`, which is **quite** handy

Answer (score 1):

Another option that I don't see here is to just extract the route function out with a function name. If all you are trying to do is writing self-documenting code.

```
function updateToDo(req, res, next) { /*do router stuff*/};
router.put('/', updateToDo);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and decided to make a library to help me out.

Besides not hardcoding your routes, it allows me to build navigation components like breadcrumbs and I can use it server side with express or client side with Backbone or whatever.

https://github.com/hrajchert/express-shared-routes

Comment: Interesting :) How do you use the named routes in jade? For example, in a form: `form(action='???' method='post' role='form' class='form-horizontal')`

Comment: I end up creating one of my own ... 4 years ago :D wow time fly.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/urls

Answer (score 0):

I thing this is what you are looking for: [Named routes](https://github.com/alubbe/named-routes)

Example code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var Router = require('named-routes');
var router = new Router();
router.extendExpress(app);
router.registerAppHelpers(app);

app.get('/admin/user/:id', 'admin.user.edit', function(req, res, next){
    // for POST, PUT, DELETE, etc. replace 'get' with 'post', 'put', 'delete', etc.

    //... implementation

    // the names can also be accessed here:
    var url = app.namedRoutes.build('admin.user.edit', {id: 2}); // /admin/user/2

    // the name of the current route can be found at req.route.name
});

app.listen(3000);
```

As you can see you can name the route as `admin.user.edit` and access it in you views

Answer (score 0):

[Check this Gist please](https://gist.github.com/loaiabdalslam/dacdada5e1982e4f625e7a6defe39896)

```
var env="http://localhost:3000/"
var route='users/:id/profile/'
var routes=[
  {
    'name':'profile',
    'path':'users/:id/:profile/'

  }
]


function RouteName(route,arg){
  let targetRoute = routes.find(e=>e.name==route).path
  for(var key in arg){

  targetRoute=targetRoute.replace(`:${key}`,arg[key])
  //console.log(targetRoute)

}
return targetRoute

}

console.log(env+RouteName('profile',{'id':3,'profile':'loaiabdalslam'}))
```