# Mongoose: Can't retrieve document by ID - Error 404

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, server

I am trying to retrieve objects from MongoDB with mongoose but I receive error 404.

```
router.get('/blogs/:id', function(req, res){
console.log('getting one blog post by id');
Blog.findOne({
   _id: req.params.id
})
   .exec(function (err, blog) {
       if(err){
           res.send('error occured');
       } else{
           console.log(blog);
           res.render('entry', {entries: entry});
       }
   })
});
```

Error message: ** 5abe5efa06ac64917363277a Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).**

The documents exists in the database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5abe5efa06ac64917363277a"),
    "title" : "this is the first blog",
    "author" : "me",
    "body" : "this is a post",
    "comments" : [ 
        ObjectId("5ac1fe92f2eb490c3c5b1357")
    ]
}
```

This is my entry.ejs view:

```html
<% include header %>
<div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-heading">

        <div class="text-muted pull-right">
            <%= entry.published %>
        </div>
        <%= entry.author  %>  <a class="btn btn-default" href="blogs/<%= entry._id %>"> <%= entry.title %></a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <%= entry.body %>
        <div id="comments">

            <% entry.comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
            <%= comment.commentAuthor + " : " + comment.comm %>
            <% }) %>
        </div>
        <div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">

        <a class="btn btn-default" href="<%= entry._id %>/new-comment">Add new comment</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

And here is how I defined my schema:

```html
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.commentSchema = new Schema({
    commentAuthor: String,
    comm: String,
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

exports.blogSchema = new Schema({
    title:  String,
    author: String,
    body:   String,
    comments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'commentSchema' }],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },

});
exports.Blog = mongoose.model('Blog',exports.blogSchema);
```

With the following code I can retrieve all blogs:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var schema = require('../model/schema');

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    schema.Blog.find({}, function (err, blogs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);

        } else{
            res.render('blogs', {entries: blogs});
        }

    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: what is the request that you are sending ?

Comment: The possible reason to this error may be , you are calling an end point which is not defined on the server side. you can verify it your route is being hit properly by logging something in the handler function

Comment: try `<%= entry.author  %>  <a class="btn btn-default" href="blogs?id=<%= entry._id %>"> <%= entry.title %></a>`

Comment: Still the same error after correcting the href...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending `string` to the `query` and it **expects an ObjectId** you are getting the error.

Try below,

**Solution 1:**

```
    import mongoose from 'mongoose';
    (or)
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    router.get('/blogs/:id', function(req, res){
    console.log('getting one blog post by id');
    Blog.findOne({
       _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)
    })
       .exec(function (err, blog) {
           if(err){
               res.send('error occured');
           } else{
               console.log(blog);
               res.render('entry', {entries: entry});
           }
       })
    });
```

**Solution 2:**

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; 

router.get('/blogs/:id', function(req, res){
console.log('getting one blog post by id');
Blog.findOne({
   _id: new ObjectId(req.params.id)
})
   .exec(function (err, blog) {
       if(err){
           res.send('error occured');
       } else{
           console.log(blog);
           res.render('entry', {entries: entry});
       }
   })
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of the solutions work. Could there be something wrong in my schema definitions? [added to post now]

Comment: are you getting this console? `getting one blog post by id`

Comment: there you are, that get request is not being called

Comment: Tried what you posted Sravan, but with no luck. It should be noted that I can retrieve and show all blog posts, it's only when I attempt to retrieve 1 post by `ObjectId` that it does not work.

Comment: can you send the code how u r reetrieving all blogs

Comment: I added to the original post now.

Comment: I cant find that

Comment: sorry, added now

Comment: Please inspect and check what html is being formed in that html

Comment: Please check this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854689/is-it-possible-to-name-routes-in-express-js)