# How to do reverse routing in an expressjs app

Tags: node.js, express

Here's an example of the express documentation

```js
app.get('/users/:userId/books/:bookId', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.params)
})
```

The question is, **how do I generate this url for a given user/book?** To put it in a template for instance.
I would want to write something like this `route.reverse({userId: userId, bookId: bookId})` but I can't find it in the doc. To me, `'/users/'+userId+'/books/'+bookId` is not a good option

How do people usually do that?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, you want a fixed route for both `userId` and `bookId`?

Comment: Yeah, to display a link on a page. Like
`<a href="/users/12/books/1">See More on this book</a>`

Comment: [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)?

Comment: also not quite sure what you mean, are either of the following links relevant:  1) [simple templating engine in express](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html) or 2)  [‘Django style’ reverse route](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10027574) ...And in regards to endpoints/routes, just to be clear, you can make them follow whatever pattern/naming convention you like.

Comment: This Django style reverse routing is not bad. But I would need to go for a custom implementation since there's not such feature in express and libs are not maintained. I found this as well https://github.com/rcs/route-parser

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug:

I had somewhat of a similar need (plus I wanted a more declarative way to write routes) so I built a lib that has a reverse-routing built it: [zemi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zemi).