# How do I define individual pages in Express.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I'm just getting started with **express.js** and am failing to understand how one defines discrete "pages" (in the traditional sense) that one can link to internally.

I'm using Jade as a template engine and I see how it pulls the various components together and references them in the app.js (which is what is initially invoked by npm) so that, in effect is my "index".  Would be great to see a tutorial on what one does to then build out pageA, pageB, pageC so that they can be linked to via `<a href="pageA.html">` (or the Jade equivalent).

I'm assuming this is possible, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Express.js` itself does not offer URL generation, only a built-in router.

You would need to use an additional package to perform URL generation, or build it yourself. Maybe you find something fitting in this question's answers: [URL generation for routes in `express`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754741/url-generation-for-routes-in-express)

If you do not care about route generation and want to "hard code" the URLs, you would need to add a **route** for each static page, like this:

```
// routes.js
app.get("/pageA.html", function(req, res, next) { res.render("static/page_a", { templateLocals: "here" }) };
app.get("/pageB.html", function(req, res, next) { res.render("static/page_b") };
```

Or, if you have many of those pages, you could use a **controller** for this:

```
// static_page_controller.js
module.exports = function(pageTemplate) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    return res.render("static/" + pageTemplate);
  }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
// routes.js
var staticController = require("./static_page_controller");

app.get("/pageA.html", staticController("page_a"));
```

Comment: wow... I wasn't expecting that that's the answer, but I guess it's correct. Thanks.

Comment: ah.. now I see what you mean... you're misunderstanding my question which was in fact directly related *to routing.

Comment: Hope I got this right this time: added a section to explain the need of routes and how they are used to render a view.

Comment: yes thanks... that's precisely what I was looking for.