# How to create href links in a view, pointing to Express routes?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to create href links inside my views, but I **do not want** to point to a static address. I want to dynamically create href urls based on routes.

Example:

```
// app.js:
app.get('/test', function testPage(req, res, next) {
    // do something here
});

// inside view.html:
<a href="path('testPage')" /> // something similar
<a href="/test" /> I do NOT want this!
```

Am I missing something, or there is no way to do that easily?

I've searched and I found that `app._router.stack` has all routes. But they are just a plain **ARRAY** so they don't have any kind of id or smth! What I came up with, is a function that parses all routes (from stack), gets their **name**, which is set **only if the function has a name** (http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.route) and then create an object with key (route name) -> path.
Then I can use this function (somehow) inside views to create paths, right?

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Coming from PHP frameworks background, I am used to two way routes. However, from what I've seen in tutorials, people just use the static links. I think it has to do with the nature of Node.js web applications. Lots of them are [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)s, so you just build an API and then refer to it statically from the frontend application.

When researching this topic, I've came accross this little library called [2-way router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/2way-router) which can be used with Express. I haven't experimented with it yet, but it might be useful to you.

EDIT: Tried to re-word my search and I've found [similar thread about url generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754741/url-generation-for-routes-in-express) and [express route naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854689/is-it-possible-to-name-routes-in-express-js).

EDIT: You can also implement [django-like routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854689/is-it-possible-to-name-routes-in-express-js/12854940#12854940).

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer! I simply can't understand how can someone use static links in a project with a few thousand links - it drives me insane. Anyways - I've already found some of the packages you posted (didn't find 2way-router, seems better than the others). What I don't like is they create a brand new `Router` class that mimics and replaces the Express Router. I'm a bit scared to use them as I don't know how they perform and what issues they have (Express is at least used a lot). Anyways thanks a lot for the effort, I might use 2way router..

Comment: Happy to help! If you are going to use either of these for your project, make sure to swipe through their Github issue tracker and see how they are mantained, so you don't choose an abandoned library. As for the `Router` class, I think it's okay, they just store the routes and then apply them to the express app. And hey, they are open source, so if there is any compatibility issue, you can alway send a pull-request or fork the repository ;)